# What will be brought in Cache when accessing variable of structure with pointer?

Tags: c, linux, pointers, caching, x86

I have a structure in C defined so that it's size of cache line (64 bytes).

```
typedef struct _list{
  int value_1;
  int value_2;
  char padding[40];
  struct _list * next;
  struct _list * prev;
} list;
```

Then if I create elements of this type

```
volatile list * el1 = malloc(sizeof(list));
el1->value_1 = 1;

volatile list * el2 = malloc(sizeof(list));
el2->value_1 = 1;

volatile list * el3 = malloc(sizeof(list));
el3->value_1 = 1;

el1->next = el2;
el2->next = el3;

volatile list * temp = el1;

//flushed above elements from cache.

temp = temp->next;
```

elements are created with gap of 16 bytes in between:

```
 el1:  value_1: 0x557816467530, next: 0x557816467560
 el2:  value_1: 0x557816467580, next: 0x5578164675b0,
```

With such code, after flushing, with disabled prefetchers, execution of the last line:

1) In cache it will only bring el1 element and modify temp so it looks at the address where el1's next is looking. This code will not cause el2 element to be brought in cache right?

2) will it bring In cache address from next variable? starting from 0x557816467560 and plus next adjacent 64 bytes? (If so In this next adjacent bytes, will be the gap 16 bytes included?)

Comment: How do you ensure that the list elements are aligned?

Comment: I started to use posix_memalign, however alignment constraint was already ensured  with malloc as well.

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I'm not aware of a malloc implementation that guarantees 64-byte alignment.

Comment: On the other hand, if you are only accessing a single field of each list element, then perhaps it doesn't matter if the list element spans two cache lines?

Comment: @AndreasAbel I modified the questions by adding small example of the code and straight the questions I was indirectly asking. Hopefully this is better way to ask a question.

Comment: @prl you are right, I don't think each element will be aligned with respect to 64 bytes, however when I access value of next, in one cache line it should bring 64 bytes starting from address of next, right? or it brings the entire element?

Comment: Also, If I have an object size of 64 bytes, which is not 64-byte aligned, accessing first element of it will bring only this object in cache right? in one cache line. Or it can be brought in two cache lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Correct. When it reads `el1->next`, it reads the cache line containing that member, but it does not read the cache line that it points to. (The processor doesn't know that the value of that field is a memory address, until it executes the instruction that dereferences it.)

2) A cache line is 64 bytes that are 64-byte aligned. If you access `next` and it is at address, say, 0x600428, then the cache line that will be read contains bytes 0x600400 - 0x60043f. The processor doesn't know what the structure size is and it doesn’t know that some parts of the structure are padding. If you access one element of a structure that spans two cache lines, the processor can’t know that, so it just reads the cache line that is accessed. (The hardware prefetcher may fetch the next line, in anticipation that it may be needed soon, but that’s unrelated to the size of the structure.)

Comment: Thank you, It's clear now. I have one additional question, it might be a bit stupid to ask this but: in temp variable it has saved the beginning address of el1 element (address of value_1), However when we access temp->next, it will try to fetch in cache the address of next variable, not value_1's address right? (let's say list object is bigger than cache line and both this variables are 64 byte-aligned). To do this, temp knows beginning address of the element, but how is offset to next variable calculated? for this who knows the structure of the object and size of each variable?

Comment: The compiler will either a) take the value in `temp`, add the offset of the structure member `next`, and use the sum as the address to load the value of `next`; or b) use a base-register+displacement addressing mode, such as `mov rax, [rax+0x30]`, where the offset of the structure member is added to the base address and then the value at that address is read, all within a single instruction.

Comment: Ah I see. I was thinking it was run time. Thank you again, this is very helpful.

Comment: Yes, it is at runtime. The compiler generates the code to perform the addition at runtime. You can see the code the compiler generates here: https://godbolt.org/z/wtgo4l

Comment: yes sure, I was skipping compiler part and thought that getting that offset also was in run time done by CPU, which I admit is stupid. and wow this website is pretty nice, so much better than looking at the file generated by objdump -d. understandable even for me.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, godbolt is amazing. For years I considered writing one myself, so I was very happy to find it.

Comment: yes especially possibility to see the connection between assembly code line and C code line directly, makes it great. That is one of my main struggles to read compiled code.

Comment: Be sure to always enable optimization when looking at compiler output to understand the compiled code.

Comment: yes good point. I noticed that and played with -O3 and -O0 as well. Again, pretty cool.